# Getting unexpected directory name in json output in Golang server

Tags: go, server, url-routing

I am new in Golang and I am trying to store image in the files on server and save its directory in MySQL Database. The code is running fine the DB is also storing the directory of the stored image correctly but the output json is showing the directory not correctly and I am not able to solve this. If also possible I want to give proper name to the saved file while creating and storing the image in the directory.I know should use [jpeg](https://golang.org/pkg/image/jpeg/#Encode) or [png](https://golang.org/pkg/image/png/) but don't know how to set directory for these. The Directory has a parent folder `profile-pic` and child folder `created from the mobile number I get form the POST Request` where the image is stored. The Code is given below main.go

```
func main() {
    host, _ := os.Hostname()
    addrs, _ := net.LookupIP(host)
    for _, addr := range addrs {
        if ipv4 := addr.To4(); ipv4 != nil {
            fmt.Println("IPv4: ", ipv4)
        }
    }
    r := httprouter.New()
    uc := controller.NewUserController(getSession())
    r.GET("/", uc.Starter)
    r.POST("/create", uc.MobileCreate)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}

func getSession() *sql.DB {
    s, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return s
}
```

controller.go

```
type UserController struct {
    session *sql.DB
}

func NewUserController(s *sql.DB) *UserController {
    return &UserController{s}
}
func (uc UserController) Starter(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
    dump, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, `Your at homepage and Connection to db was success and check the terminal for dump diagnosis!`)
    fmt.Println("Request Dump:\n", string(dump))
}

func (uc UserController) MobileCreate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
    r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20)
    UserName := r.FormValue("name")
    EmailId := r.FormValue("email")
    PassWord := r.FormValue("password")
    MobileNumber := r.FormValue("mobile")
    i, _ := strconv.ParseInt(MobileNumber, 0, 64)
    AddRess := r.FormValue("address")
    ProfilePic, _, err := r.FormFile("profilePic")
    DirectoryName := "profile-pics" + "\\" + MobileNumber
    _ = DirectoryName + "\\" + "dp.png"
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error Retrieving the File")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer ProfilePic.Close()

    _, err = os.Stat("test")
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        errDir := os.MkdirAll("profile-pics"+"\\"+MobileNumber, 0755)
        if errDir != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

    }

    tempFile, err := ioutil.TempFile("profile-pics"+"\\"+MobileNumber, "*.png")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer tempFile.Close()

    fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(ProfilePic)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // write this byte array to our temporary file
    tempFile.Write(fileBytes)
    u := models.User{
        Name:       UserName,
        Email:      EmailId,
        Password:   PassWord,
        Mobile:     i,
        Address:    AddRess,
        ProfilePic: tempFile.Name(),
    }

    query, err := uc.session.Prepare("Insert loggedin SET name=?, email=?,pwd=?,number=?,address=?,profilepic=?")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = query.Exec(u.Name, u.Email, u.Password, u.Mobile, u.Address, u.ProfilePic)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer query.Close()

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated) // 201
    err = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(u)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

model/user.go

```
type User struct {
    Name       string `json:"name" `
    Email      string `json:"email" `
    Password   string `json:"password" `
    Mobile     int64  `json:"mobile" `
    Address    string `json:"address" `
    ProfilePic string `json: image`
}
```

The entry in database is correct

[image]

The json Output

```
"profile-pics\\9041111113\\103561439.png"
```

I tried naming the img to dp but the img was then saved in unsupported format

[image]

I want to remove double `\\`because i have to load this image in android app with picasso lib and it doesn't convert `\\` to single `\`

```
 Picasso.get()
            .load(json output as string)
            .into(imageView)
```

I want to save the image in png only.

Comment: The json output is correct. Backslashes are escaped.

Comment: but i have to use this output in picasso lib in android to load the image and that lib. doesn't take this kind of input. it takes only single \

Comment: Any conforming JSON parser will interpret escaped backslash correctly. Are you passing this to the library as JSON, or as string? How are you processing the data from the db?

Comment: If the backslashes were not escaped, it would be invalid. If you're parsing it as JSON, the escaped backslashes will be parsed as the expected strings with single backslashes in them. If you're examining the data in the DB directly and worried about it, stop. It's fine. If you're getting the values back with backslashes in them in code, then the problem is in your code, and you'll need to include the relevant code in the body of your question.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I have updated the question with how i will use this output in android app.

Comment: @Adrian I have posted the whole code i wrote.

Comment: What does this mean: `load(json output as string)` If you're using JSON output as string, then probably that's your problem. It is JSON, not a string, you have to decode it. How do you convert JSON output to string?

Comment: @BurakSerdar on android we have retrofit library for all the request & response. we use variables stated in a data class. Retrofit scans the json and match the json fields with the data class variables . We directly extract value corresponding to matched field in json and use it. So there is isn't much of a choice, thats why I want to solve this output issue on the server side (Golang) only.

Comment: @MohitYadav Why are you using backslashes? Are you working on a Windows machine? Are the images on your Windows machine? Or are the images on the Android device? Does Android use backslashes for file paths? Or, does it not matter whether it's a backslash or forwardslash and `Picasso` knows how to handle both?

Comment: @MohitYadav, when you encode the string "a\b\c" to JSON, it is "a\\b\\c", and when you decode it it becomes "a\b\c" again. If you send that string as a JSON value to your client side, you have to decode it.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for the Questions, answering them made me realize the solution. Initially i saw the backslash in windows directory. Yeah for local development i am using windows. I generate a post request from android device from where i receive the data and i write back json as response.I changed  from \ to / and it worked like a charm. Just one more request can u help me with how to display the image stored in the files as a separate web page (example:-https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60)

Comment: @MohitYadav [`FileServer`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) should be enough I think, make sure you set it up properly with the correct root and, if necessary, StripPrefix also. Read the documentation, look at the examples there, and if you can't make it work try searching, there's on SO already lots of Q&As related to this.